# Storage Hosting Services for Mobile App?

Tags: php, android, mysql, laravel, hosting

Im currently developing a mobile app which heavily uses a lot of uploading of images somewhat like fb, snapchat, etc. but on a smaller scale. Currently, uploaded images are stored in a folder just inside the project folder.

Should I be placing it in a blob in mysql instead? Or are there services maybe dedicated for storing of files like images and videos for these kind of application which I should be using instead?

Im currently using laravel for the back end/REST API.

Comment: Amazon s3 is a good place to start.

Comment: Using MySQL to store files is usually a very bad idea for performance.

Comment: I second what @Devon has said. This is such an opinionated question as everyone will have their own take on it. Have you tried searching around, there are quite a few different services offering what you are after.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Do you guys know which among amazon s3 and firebase cloud storage would be cheaper for storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try **[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/?authuser=0).**

It comes with database and a storage - all on the cloud. It has some other cool features:

- [firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/)
- [test lab](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/) (android only)
- [authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/)
- [hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/)
- [ads](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/)
- [analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/)
- [cloud messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)
- and so much more

It is configurable on different platforms, here's the **[guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/guides/?authuser=0)** page to get you started.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, do you know whether firebase cloud storage would cost more or less compared to amazon s3?

Comment: i'm not sure, here's s3 pricing: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/ and here's firebase pricing: https://firebase.google.com/pricing/